# How to apply font-size:medium to entire site with mediaquery css

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a styles.css file. Now i'm going to write css - media queries for mobiles/tablet devices. In styles.css, i mentioned differnt font-sizes to diffent classes. Now i need to apply all 'font-size's to 'medium' for mobile devices. How to apply?

i have applied font-size:medium; to mediaqueries css. it is working fine. but for ex:.dynamicdata{font-size:14px;} in style.css. i need to  apply replace font-size:medium to all classes which i have applied fonts-sizes for mediaqueires css.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this...

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

  /* disable webkit text size adjust (for iPhone) */
  html {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  }
  .class1, .class2, .class3 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
}
```